# Disable the "restart" option in Ctrl Alt Delete menu

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. 5 years of muscle memory makes me hit ctrl-alt-delete then enter before walking away from my PC at work. On Ubuntu the default option that selects is restart. This has been a bit of a problem. How can I change it? I either want to remove the restart option or make the lock option primary. I looked around but cant find a way to do it.

Comment: which decktop are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For most desktops got to `control center` or `system settings`
Click on `keyboard` then `shortcuts` tab.

Scroll through the list of preset shortcuts. You should find `logout`, `Lock screen`, and `shut down` together.

Click on the one you want to change, then press the short cut to use.

In your case:
Select `shut down` then <kbd>backspace</kbd> to disable shut down.
Then, select `Logout` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to set it.